# Postfix & external domain account at gmail

Tags: postfix, web-applications, gmail

I need some help with a postfix server && a google apps gmail account.

Basically, I have a mail server to handle example.org accounts. At the same time, I have a google apps account for the domain, which manages this email account: example@example.org.

The problem is that when the local server tries to deliver a message to example@example.org, it obviously tries to deliver it locally, but I need that messages to arrive to the external gmail account.

Anyone knows a trick to tell postfix to deliver that concrete email address not locally?

Thanks in advance, Simon.

Comment: I may be wrong but is it so called *relay*?

Comment: The mail would loop-back it itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your gmail account have a username@gmail.com address? If so just forward to that address.
or use postfix [transport(_maps)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html):

```
example@example.org  smtp:gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25
```